# Is there any way to implemet the back button in the Toolbar only using XML?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button, android-theme, back

I have seen many different solutions to add the back button in the Toolbar and then implement the behaviour through code. However, I was wondering if there is any way to add the button and implement its behaviour only using XML. For example, using a specific Android Theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a theme you can't achieve this. If you want to achieve only through XML, try adding a toolbar and inside keep a container layout (Relative or Linear) and add ImageButton with a back arrow vector. Give an onClick handler to it and implement the logic in the method.